# How can I have two or more static Blocks On a Magento Page

Tags: magento-1.4, magento-1.5, magento

I am customizing the home page and i want to add two static blocks (actually 2 Images) to it, One at The Top and one at bottom.. While I was navigating through CMS/Static Blocks, I realized I can Only add One Static Block to any page. I couldn't find anything where i can  add 2 or more static blocks. Is there a way i can add two or more such static blocks in a single page..

Comment: In the case you want to add two static blocks to a cms page define two static blocks for your pictures and add them in the wysiwyg editor by using the blockname you defined: 

`{{block type="cms/block" block_id="pictureone"}}
some content
{{block type="cms/block" block_id="picturetwo"}}`

Comment: Thanks @Danny. I am new to magento and ur answer seems a bit confusing to me can u please expand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.

1. go to **CMS > Static Blocks** and create two new blocks with your images, remember the identifier
2. go to **CMS > Pages** and select the cms page where you want to place your images
3. open the cms page and and put the following in the editor, where you want to appear your images: {{block type="cms/block" block_id="**IDENTIFIER**"}}

If you want to put your images on other pages than cms pages you need to modify the specific layout file. A good point to start with this: http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/demystifying-magentos-layout-xml-part-1/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a Lot I did and And I got a static block on home page at the Top, but how would I do it with a non cms page. eg I have a Category page or Any other page And Is there a way I can move it and Place it just above my footer link.. ?

Comment: you can do this by editing the xml files in your layout folder. the tutorial mentioned above or this tutorial: http://alanstorm.com/layouts_blocks_and_templates should show you how to place blocks by using the update handles. i think there are also a lot of explanations on stackoverflow that are helpful for you. just search for "block" or look into the standard layout xml files. good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in the template file (phtml file) where you want your blocks to be displayed.

For first block,

```
    <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('block1_identifier')->toHtml() ?>
```

then for second block,

```
    <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('block2_identifier')->toHtml() ?>
```